# listbox selected value retorna vacio

Tags: c#, asp.net

al seleccionar un item de un listbox este me retorna un string vacío al momento de cargar la pagina lleno el listbox

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Consultas consulta = new Consultas();
        string cmd = "SELECT * FROM TIPOTARJETA";
        DataTable dt = consulta.Consutar(cmd);
        tipoT.DataSource = dt;
        tipoT.DataTextField = "Descripcion";
        tipoT.DataValueField = "ID";
        tipoT.DataBind();
    }
```

y en el evento de un botón llamo al valor seleccionado:

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipot", Int64.Parse(tipoT.SelectedValue));
```

pero me retorna un string completamente vació y por ende no hace el parseo

Comment: Debes tener un elemento seleccionado, por ejemplo el primero con `tipoT.SelectedIndex = 0;`

Comment: No se si aplique pero los nombres de los campos seguro que son esos?, creo que deben ser exactos para que funcione.

Comment: Y en este caso porque tienes select * ? selecciona solo los campos que necesitas...

Comment: Lo que noto es que tenes la consulta sobre el metodo Page_Load, y ese metodo carga la pagina, como quieres que sepa que hay un item seleccionado?

Comment: a todos muchas gracias el problema era que no verificaba el postback de la pagina y al presionar el botón recargaba la pagina y perdía la selección